# Connection Reset Error

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

It is a Client Server application. Client has two threads, thread 1 takes screen shots, and thread2 sends them to server, and server will receive images and save them on local storage.
Steps are:
thread 1

1. Client takes Screenshots
2. save images on local storage and their paths in a Queue(Q_image)
   thread 2
3. dequeue paths , read images from storage and send them to server one by one.
4. Server receive images, respond with TRUE to client and save them in a folder
   (asynchronous client server communication)

I want client to take infinite images and server t receive infinite images but I got the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageInputStream.readUntil(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInputData(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImage(Native Method)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at Server.main(Server.java:34)
```

**Server:**

```
     public class Server extends Thread
 {
   static BufferedImage RecievedImage;
   static Socket clientSocket = null;
   static DataOutputStream dos;
  static ServerSocket serversock;
  static int flag=0;
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,      InterruptedException
 {
  serversock = new ServerSocket(1234);
    clientSocket = serversock.accept();
    dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
  try{ 
   while (true) {

    RecievedImage = ImageIO.read(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("Image RECIEVED successfully");
    if (RecievedImage != null) {

        dos.writeBoolean(true);

        File RecievedImageFile = new File(path+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        dos.writeBoolean(true);

        System.out.println("REQUESTED FOR NEW IMAGE ");
        ImageIO.write(RecievedImage, "jpg", RecievedImageFile);
        System.out.println("Image file written successfully");
    } else {
        dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBoolean(false);
        System.out.println("SENT FALSE ");
        System.out.println("image is empty ");
    }
}
           }
  finally{

    //  dos.close();
        //clientSocket.close();
    //  serversock.close(); 

        }   
   }
}
```

**Cient**

```
 abstract class ScreenCapture extends Thread {
 static BufferedImage screencapture; 
static DataInputStream dis;
  static String img_path = null;
  static Socket ClientSocket;
   static Queue Q_image= new Queue();
   static String path1;
   static int flag=0;
   public static void main(String args[]) throws
       AWTException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    try {

        ClientSocket = new Socket("localhost",1234);

          dis = new DataInputStream(ClientSocket.getInputStream()); 

         while(true) {
        //First thread that is Taking screenshot
        Thread TakeScreenShotthread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {

                    screencapture = new Robot()
                            .createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit
                                    .getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

                    path = path+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                    File image = new File(path);
                    ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", image);

                    Q_image.enqueue(path);
                    System.out.println("thread1 is running...");

                } catch (HeadlessException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (AWTException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
    //Thread 2 that is Sending Screenshot to server
        Thread sendingScreenShotThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                BufferedImage img;

                //Sending Screen to Server
                try {
                    if (flag == 0) {
                        img_path = (String) Q_image.dequeue();
                        img = ImageIO.read(new File(img_path));
                        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg",ClientSocket.getOutputStream());
                        System.out.println(" FLAG ZERO .. " +path+img_path);
                        flag++;
                    }

                    if (dis.readBoolean()) {
                        System.out
                                .println(" WAITNING FOR SERVER RESPONSE ..");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } else {

                        img_path = (String) Q_image.dequeue();
                        img = ImageIO.read(new File(img_path));
                        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg",
                                ClientSocket.getOutputStream());
                        System.out
                                .println("thread2 is running.   RETURNED ..");
                    }

                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
        TakeScreenShotthread.start();
        TakeScreenShotthread.sleep(200);
        sendingScreenShotThread.start();
        sendingScreenShotThread.sleep(200);

         }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (flag==3) {
            //Closing ClientS
            dis.close();
            ClientSocket.close();
        }
    }

 }
```

}

Comment: First guess would be that your socket's inputstream gets closed somehow. I'd try to keep a reference in the scope of outside the while loop and pass that to `ImageIO.read`.

Comment: I didn't get you? What should be the solution?